# Monochromatic square in colored plane

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

> **Square Theorem.** Color every point in the real plane using a finite amount of colors. Show there exists a square whose vertices are monochromatic.

I am aware this question [is a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242724/monochromatic-squares-in-a-colored-plane?rq=1), however, the answers given there don't really prove the statement. Despite there being references quoted, they all seem to be lacking a proof as well.

I am also aware this is a consequence of Gallai's Theorem, which states

> **Gallai's Theorem.** Color every point in $\mathbb R^n$ using a finite amount of colors. Let $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a finite set. Then there is a monochromatic subset $A'\subset\mathbb R^n$ that is homothetic (i.e., similar and parallel) to $A$.

This theorem is so unpopular there is not even a Wikipedia page about it, but one may find a proof in the great *The Mathematical Coloring Book* (which do have its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Coloring_Book)). Still, the book mentions two existing direct proofs for the Square Theorem, one through [Van der Waerden's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) and the other through a strategy similar to Van der Waerden's Theorem's proof, none of which it presents nor I've found elsewhere. It seems I'm not the only one: [this presentation](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/papers/gridtalk.pdf) cites two supposed direct proofs for the Square Theorem as "folklore".

Anyway, is there a direct proof for the Square Theorem? Does anyone knows it? I have not even been able to find a proof for the three color case and its preventing me to sleep for so long now.

Comment: There's another Gasarch reference, https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/250/S15/monosq.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to discuss the stronger "combinatorial" square theorem, which states:

> For each integer $r>0$ there is some $n>0$ such that, whenever $[n]^2$ is $r$-colored, there exists a set of the form $$\{(x,y), (x+d,y), (x,y+d), (x+d,y+d)\}$$ whose four elements all receive the same color.

Here (and later), $[n]$ refers to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

The combinatorial square theorem implies the square theorem in $\mathbb R^2$, since we can draw $[n]^2$ as a grid in $\mathbb R^2$. Looking at the theorem in the plane also allows "lopsided" squares; it seems unlikely, but possible, that those make the proof easier.

The combinatorial theorem is sandwiched between the length-$4$-AP case of [van der Waerden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) and the size-$4$-alphabet case of the [Hales–Jewett theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem) in the Ramsey-type theorem hierarchy. Specifically, there are maps
$$
    [4]^d \longrightarrow [2^d]^2 \longrightarrow [3 \cdot 2^d] 
$$
such that every combinatorial line in $[4]^d$ maps to a square in $[2^d]^2$ (though not all squares are obtained in this way), and every square in $[2^d]^2$ maps to a length-$4$ arithmetic progression in $[3\cdot 2^d]$ (though not all arithmetic progressions are obtained in this way).

This means that the Hales–Jewett theorem implies the square theorem. Given an $r$, let $d$ be the Hales–Jewett number for a size-$4$ alphabet and $r$ colors, and take $n=2^d$. Any $r$-coloring of $[n]^2$ can be pulled back to a coloring of $[4]^d$, which must contain a combinatorial line, and the image of that combinatorial line is a monochromatic square in our coloring of $[n]^2$.

This also means that the square theorem implies the length-$4$-AP case of van der Waerden's theorem. Given an $r$, choose $n$ large enough that the $n/3$ by $n/3$ grid is big enough for the square theorem. Any $r$-coloring of $[n]$ can be pulled back to a coloring of $[n/3]^2$, which must contain a monochromatic square, and the image of that monochromatic square is a length-$4$ AP in our coloring of $[n]$.

For this reason, the square theorem should not have a proof significantly easier than van der Waerden's theorem, unless the length-$4$ case is easier than the general case to prove.

---

Here are the details of the two maps mentioned earlier.

The map from $[4]^d$ to $[2^d]^2$ is defined recursively. To map $[4]$ to $[2]^2$, send $1$ to $(1,1)$, $2$ to $(1,2)$, $3$ to $(2,1)$, and $4$ to $(2,2)$. To map $[4]^d$ to $[2^d]^2$, separate $[4]^d$ out into $4$ copies of $4^{d-1}$, with last coordinate $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$. Map each copy to $[2^{d-1}]^2$. Then shift the second copy over by $(0,2^{d-1})$, the third copy over by $(2^{d-1},0)$, and the fourth copy over by $(2^{d-1},2^{d-1})$. The effect of this is that a combinatorial line which changes coordinates in a set $I \subseteq [d]$ corresponds to a square with side length $\sum_{i \in I} 2^{i-1}$.

The map from $[2^d]^2$ to $[3 \cdot 2^d]$ is much simpler: the point $(x,y)$ is mapped to $x+2y$. A square $\{(x,y), (x+d,y), (x,y+d), (x+d,y+d)\}$ is mapped to $\{x+y, x+y+d, x+y+2d, x+y+3d\}$, which is an arithmetic progression of length $4$.